# How to write a Ruby "if" statement in HAML

Tags: ruby, haml

```
- entries.each do |entry|
    - if !isOpen
      - columnClass = 'col-1'
    - if entry[:variant] == 'medium'
      - columnClas = 'col-2'
    - if entry[:variant] == 'larg'
      - columnClas = 'col-3'
    %div{:class => "GridTeaserArea--column #{columnClass}"}
      = component 'GridTeaser', entry
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read "[ask]" and its linked pages, along with "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
"[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)". Proper formatting is important on SO. Formatting properly helps us help you. Did you research this? If not, why? If so, why didn't it help? What errors are you seeing or what is the problem? This is well documented by the [Haml documentation](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
- isOpen = false
- entries.each do |entry|
 - if !isOpen
  - columnClass = 'col-1'
  :ruby
   if (entry[:variant] == 'medium')
    columnClass = 'col-2'
   end
   if (entry[:variant] == 'larg')
    columnClass = 'col-3'
   end
     = "<div class='GridTeaserArea--column #{columnClass}'>"

 = component 'GridTeaser', entry
```

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just need more indentations with `if` and rearrangement.

```
- entries.each do |entry|
    - if !isOpen
      - columnClass = 'col-1'
    - if entry[:variant] == 'medium'
      - columnClas = 'col-2'
    - if entry[:variant] == 'larg'
      - columnClas = 'col-3'
    %div{:class => "GridTeaserArea--column #{columnClass}"}
      = component 'GridTeaser', entry
```

Change code as per the logic you have in mind. I tried to show how to use an `if` conditional inside `HAML`. The code output may not be what you desired, as it is not stated, I didn't attempt to assume it.

Please read [HAML tutorial](http://haml.info/tutorial.html) to get yourself comfortable with HAML.

Comment: thanks for answering but i had syntax error in the browser

Comment: I attempted to assume your thought to give it a shape.